# Extra library in same site or different sub site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, sub-site

We currently have one big document library within our `Sharepoint 2013` intranet. Because this library contains more than 10k documents we want to split it up in a second document library 'archive'. The main library will hold all the active documents.

What is the best solutions for this regarding permissions, migrations, flexibility, etc?

1. Add another document library on the same level.
2. Add a separate subsite and create the document library in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it's best to do it at the same site.  Mainly, because users are familiar with that location.  Secondly, it will be easy to  copy any special permissions from the original library in the case permission inheritance was removed for it.

For archives, your best solution depends on your business needs.   If there will exist more than 10k 'active' documents, then you will need another approach.

If more than 10k 'active' documents are needed by your users, then you should divide the documents up logically to your needs and create separate libraries at the same level based on your division until you can be sure all active documents will be under the 10k limit.

For archiving your documents that would be able to migrate to newer versions of SharePoint, look into setting up [Information Management Policies](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-apply-information-management-policies-eb501fe9-2ef6-4150-945a-65a6451ee9e9) .  In general, it's better to use SharePoints out of the box functionality rather than roll a homemade solution.  It will save you time and money in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Better to keep the Archive library in same level. Because if you want to migrate that to new server or site, It is easy to take Site template and import it to new site.